# Capture the entire text string and convert it to asterisks

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code which generates a type of style that hides part of a text in asterisks.

```
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value 
      ? value.replace(/\B\w+@/g, (c, ) => c.split('').slice(0, -1).map(v => '*').join('') + '@') 
      : value;
  }
```

The result is this example image:

[image]

What I would like to do is to be able to mask also the first letter and that everything remains in aterisks except the mail, for example: *****@email.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following

```
/\B\w+@/g
```

with just

```
/\w+@/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regex `/.+?(?=@)/g`

```
var emailRegex = /.+?(?=@)/g;
var email = 'test@email.com';
var text = email.match(emailRegex)[0];
email = email.replace(emailRegex, '*'.repeat(text.length));
```